# How to make font size title of \chapsubhead and \section similar in Latex?

Tags: fontsize

I am facing a problem in setting a font size of \section heading  and \chaptersubhead heading. I have following code:

```
   \subsubsection{Geometrical Parameters}
        My name is John.

      \newcommand{\chapsubhead}[2]{{\normalsize #1}} 
      \chapsubhead{\flushleft \textbf {1. Time Delay}}
       John is a good boy.
```

Can anybody suggest me how to make these fonts of headings of \section and \chapsubhead same font style and fontsize in latex.

Comment: KOMA-Script, Memoir and fancyhdr all have different commands to change the formatting of headers, but they all let you insert a `\fontsize` command into the formatting.

Comment: I am using KOMA-Script but i am facing difficulty that how to change fonr size and style of headings in them. Can u please help with commands

Comment: Okay, the `\chapsubhead` command doesn’t seem to be defined correctly.

Comment: By the way, a MWE and a description of what you want would make it easier to help.

Answer (score 1):

Since yous say you are using KOMA_Script, the command you are looking for is `\minisec` ([documented here](http://mirrors.rit.edu/CTAN/macros/latex/contrib/koma-script/doc/scrguien.pdf#section.3.16)).

```
\documentclass[headings=normal]{scrartcl}
\usepackage{fontspec}

\setkomafont{minisec}{\usekomafont{subsubsection}}

\begin{document}
   \subsubsection{Geometrical Parameters}
        My name is John.

   \minisec{1. Time Delay}
       John is a good boy.
\end{document}
```

[image: minisec sample]

To change only the size to match, you could

```
\addtokomafont{minisec}{\usesizeofkomafont{subsubsection}}
```

Any font you load should be properly scaled to the same height, if you use the `fontspec` command

```
\defaultfontfeatures{ Scale = MatchUppercase }
```

If you do this, and change your main font, load it with `[Scale=1.0]` to scale everything to it, not the unused default.

Comment: I have one question that due to use of \minisec the title displays in Table of Content or not. I dont want to show this in table of contents.

Comment: @AhmadBilal They do not. You can also control whether sections, sub-sections and sub-sub-sections show up in the ToC.

Comment: @AhmadBilal You’re welcome. If nobody else posts a better answer, please consider accepting this one.